# Ubuntu edge/touch Laptop shell

Tags: ubuntu-touch, ubuntu-edge

The convergence idea is really cool and I love how you can dock your phone and use it as a full desktop by connecting it to a hdmi display.

However there is a piece of the convergence story missing and that is laptops. Does ubuntu have plans for a laptop shell, (screen and keyboard but no motherboard or processor) which I can dock my ubuntu touch/edge into and have a complete laptop experience?

If not is there any hardware available or coming soon which would allow this?

Comment: This looks off-topic.

Comment: This looks like it's all about speculation and coming features. The  Ubuntu Edge hasn't been released yet and until then we don't know more about it than you do. All the information about it is available at the indiegogo page.

Answer (score 3):

Mark on the reddit AMA said that accessories are beyond the scope.
They are hoping for third parties to create them probably using another crowd funded campaign. 
I think this is out of their scope though.
They want to revolutionize the mobile industry, not the laptop accessories business which can be left to existing players.

For example there is already a case that should work since it uses the MLD connector though I cannot find the link for it right now. Hopefully somebody that has the link handy will post it.

Answer (score 1):

One posibility is the **ClamBook** which has MHL connecter (not out yet) http://clamcase.com/clambook-android-and-iphone-laptop-dock.html

Also the **Casetop** http://livi-design.com/

So some hardware is already coming out that will do this, and probably in time for your Edge.